#  +  = ☠; how to prevent shutdown when cat presses physical button?

Tags: shutdown

My cat keeps "unintentionally" pressing my desktop's shutdown button.

How do I make this button do nothing?

UPDATE: I use standard Ubuntu 20.04.

UPDATE 2: I use VMWare, and what actually happens is that the active VM guest (and ONLY the active guest) shuts down. I assumed that it was the Guest itself responding to the physical key and shutting down, but I suppose it's possible that the VMWare host software forces this...

Comment: See `man logind.conf`

Comment: Hardware hack: Glue a tack to it.

Comment: @Fiximan by "it" you mean the button, right?

Comment: You should buy your cat her own [Cat-top](https://technabob.com/blog/2015/08/17/cat-laptop-scratching-post/) ;-)

Answer (score 4):

To disable the power button in standard Ubuntu (which we assume you use since you did not provide information on the DE you use), issue following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'nothing'
```

Undo, i.e., reset to default with

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action
```

Comment: I tried. It didn't work :( but it's possible that I omitted an important detail: I use VMWare, and what actually happens is that the active VM guest (and ONLY the active guest) shuts down. I assumed that it was the Guest itself responding to the physical key and shutting down, but I suppose it's possible that the VMWare host software forces this... At any case, I tried your suggestion in both the VM guest and the VM host (both are Ubuntu 20.04), and it didn't work :(

Comment: That indeed will not work in a virtual machine.